# Config param are undefined in error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a config file that just sets the process.env data to params.
It works fine and I can use it correctly everywhere but on my unexpected exceptions handler I can't use it... all the params from the config file are undefined.

my config file:

```
module.exports = {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
};
```

here is my uncaught exception catcher:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
    errorManagement.handler.handleError(error);
    if (!errorManagement.handler.isTrustedError(error)) process.exit(1);
});
```

and here is error handler, env is undefined, everywhere else env is defined

```
const {
    env,
 } = require('../../config');
const logger = require('../../libraries/logger');
const mailer = require('../../libraries/mailer');

function ErrorHandler() {
    this.handleError = async (err) => {
        console.log(env);
    };
}

module.exports.handler = new ErrorHandler();
```

tree of my project folder:

[image: tree of my project folder]

**EDIT:**

I found the problem but I'm still not sure why it happened...
in my config.js file I did:

```
const errorManager = require('./components/errorManagement');

[
    'DB_USER',
].forEach((name) => {
    if (typeof process.env[name] === 'undefined') {
        throw new errorManager.AppError('Environment var missing', 500, `Environment variable ${name} is missing`, true);
    }
});
```

when I deleted the error manager and used express Error everything worked as expected

Comment: Could you run a `tree` in your project folder so we can see how your structure is setup?

Comment: @mralanlee done

Comment: Where is the config.js? Is it in the root directory as well?

Comment: yes @SándorBakos

Comment: @ronmar how are you setting your `NODE_ENV`? `NODE_ENV` should get unset every the process.exits. Usually what I would set in my run script is `NODE_ENV=dev node index.js`

Comment: @mralanlee I'm using  dotenv, in my package.json I set a script: nodemon -r dotenv/config ./bin/www.
I found my problem but I'm not sure what happened.. you can see at the edit